# XAMPP cannot require parent directory

Tags: php, xampp

I'm facing following problem:

In my php file I try to require a file which is located in different directory.

```
require (__DIR__."../../../../library/test.php");
```

When I launch the the page in which I want the file to be required, this error appears:

> require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Webcontrol\app\modules\nastaveni\ajax\import../../../../library/test.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs')

It seems that php "thinks" that I am entering the absolute address to the file I want to require and I don't know how to "tell" it that I want to enter a relative address.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__DIR__` returns the path without trailing slash. And that is visible in the error you get. So just change your require to 
`require (__DIR__."/../../../../library/test.php");`